# Web Scraping from Oddschecker using BeatifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I was previously able to scrape data from https://www.oddschecker.com/ using BeautifulSoup, however, now all I am getting is the following 403 status:

```
import requests
import bs4

result = requests.get("https://www.oddschecker.com/")
result.text
```

Output:

```
<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n
```

I want to know if this is the same for all users on this website or if there is a way to navigate around this (via another web scraping package or other code) and access the actual data visible on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a user agent. It detects if your a bot by disabling js.

```
url = 'https://www.oddschecker.com/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(result.text)
```

You can also use selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver.get("https://www.oddschecker.com/")
print(driver.page_source)
```